# How can I add a control derived from TabPage to a TabControl through the Windows Forms Designer?

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

I'm new to C# and Visual Studio. I have some experience working with Java before. So I want to create a class (e.g. MyTabPage) which extends TabPage and contains some predefined elements, so I can just add it to a TabControl collection. Is there a way to set this custom TabPage with the Windows Forms designer?

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't try.  You always end up in code, so I just go there from square one.  I like having total control, and not splitting things between designer and code-behind.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments on this question, I don't think this is possible. I think the Windows Forms designer code for the TabControl is only aware of the base TabPage class. You will likely have to set this up in code yourself. If you do something like this in your form's constructor Load event, you should get something similar to what you're trying to do:

```
Dim tabPageToAdd As New MyTabPage()
theTabControl.TabPages.Add(tabPageToAdd)
```

This makes use of the [TabControl.TabPageCollection.Add(TabPage)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/68d9sedf(v=vs.110).aspx) method.